# How is $q_{\alpha,k,N-k}$ in Tukey's test calculated?

Tags: tukey-hsd-test

On the wikipedia page for [Tukey's range test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tukey%27s_range_test#Confidence_limits), under section `Confidence Limits`, a quantity

$$q_{\alpha,k,N-k}$$

makes an appearance. Unfortunately, it is not defined in the main text.

> What is this quantity, and what is the formula to calculate it numerically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the critical value from the [studentized range distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Studentized_range_distribution).

- $k$ in the question is the same as from the Wikipedia page
- $N-k$ is the degrees of freedom, $\nu$ in the Wikipedia page
- $\alpha$ is the Type I error rate. You use it to compute the critical value, which you find just like a critical value from a T or normal distribution

I would've thought for a two-sided test, it's be $q_{\alpha/2}$ rather than $q_\alpha$ but I'm not super familiar with Tukey's range test.